# how to set a imageview at center dynamically on tableview cell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm wondering how to set an imageview to the center of a tableview cell dynamically.

Here is my current code.

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100, 20, 20)];


imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"friendsCelluserpic.png"];


cell.imageView.image = imgView.image;
```

Comment: use the cells width and height then offset it by the size of your image?

Comment: i m confused pls tell me more about your answer . thanks

Comment: imageView.center = CGPointMake(cell.contentView.bounds.size.width/2,cell.contentView.bounds.size.height/2);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can code like this `[cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];`

Comment: its working perfectly , then i want to set my cell colour gray and how can add image on navigation baar ??

Comment: use this code: `cell.backgroundView = [UIView new];
    cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :
This will align your image horizontally centre in TableViewCell

```
    float imgwidth=40;
    float imgheight=40;

    imgView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((cell.contentView.bounds.size.width/2)-(imgwidth/2),15, imgwidth, imgheight)] autorelease];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, :)

```
UIImageView * imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"friendsCelluserpic.png"]];
imgView.frame=CGRectMake(100, 100, 20, 20);

[cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
return cell;
```